# iOS - What is the proper way to just display back button and no navigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

[image]

Above design can be achieve using setNavigationBarHidden = YES and by adding UIButton at the top for backButton behavior. But I wanna avoid this hack/method.

Is it possible I can still use leftBarButtonItems for backButton without navigationBar ?

What is the recommended and proper approach for this kind of design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leftBarButtonItems is an accessory which is only used with navigation bar, if you want to use that you will only use it with navigation bar.

Now if you dont want to add the custom button, then just make the `UINavigationBar` transparent using the below code.

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

[leftBarButtonItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItems) is the property of UINavigation item , so you can not use it without navigationbar. So probably if you dont want to use navigationbar adding custom button is way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without even hiding the navigation bar like

```
 UIButton *backBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 60, 20)];
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar_back_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // use your image or setText of backBtn "<"
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pushBackBtnTpd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;

    -(IBAction)pushBackBtnTpd:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```